# use VSCode's encoding setting to read a buffer

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing a VSCode extension that register a custom editor, this editor uses a webview to show the file.

I am using "Buffer.toString" to read the text part of the file, I would like use the setting "file.encoding" to use the current encoding but the values looks does not correspond to nodejs ones.. there is some package I can use for this? maybe I miss some VSCode API methods?

I would like also add the possibility of "reopen with encoding" on my editor. Is it possible use the already exists menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that VSCode uses [iconv-lite](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite) to support different encoding, and I must do from scratch the support for "reopen with encoding"